# duplicate jobs in sun grid engine

Tags: qsub, sungridengine, grid-computing

When I run qacct with the job ID, after it is finished, I get two results,
the one I run and an older job with the same jobid.

how can I delete the history of qacct?

Any one know how to solve this?
Thanks
Tsvi

Answer (score 1):

Grid Endine (or SGE) has job IDs in the range 0..99999. This may roll over quickly in some clusters and people may be interested in finding statistics of older jobs with the same ID. You can identify your jobs knowing also the approximate submit time.

Anyway if you want to eliminate the duplicate job IDs from qacct you can rotate the accounting file (//common/accounting) using utilities like logchecker.sh.

Check the man page or this grid engine online documentation:
http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/howto/rotatelogs.html